# HTTP2 does not work with AVPlayer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem, avurlasset

Currently I'm trying to send the token via headers in Swift but looks like the problem consist in HTTP2.

Example:

AVURLAsset

```
 let headers: [AnyHashable : Any] = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Bearer \(token)"
    ]
 let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl)
 let subtitleAsset = AVURLAsset(url: vttURL, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers])
```

---

Error

```
Task <B2755FA5-132C-4EE2-A72F-269EAEA8035C>.<5> finished with error [100] Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <B2755FA5-132C-4EE2-A72F-269EAEA8035C>.<5>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x600000ff2300 [0x7fff80617cb0]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb0de06a770000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <B2755FA5-132C-4EE2-A72F-269EAEA8035C>.<5>"
```

---

Related issues

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/105771
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/debugging_https_problems_with_cfnetwork_diagnostic_logging